# If $AX=B$ and $A'X=B'$ are equivalent if $[A|B] \sim [A'|B']$, show that inverse is not true

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

It is known that :

if $AX = B $ and $A'X = B'$ ;

then $ [A|B] \sim [A'|B']$

On the other hand, how can I show that converse of that definition is not true for all conditions.

Comment: What is $[A\mid B]$= And what does $\sim$ mean?

Comment: [A | B] means augmented matrice of A and B  _and_  $\sim$ means A and B are row equivalent